# How to get location name by using latitude and longitude values

Tags: iphone

In my application i have to get the location name using latitude and longitude values, I think we can get them through reverse geocoding is there any method that we can use and get the location value

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yeah we can use MKReverseGeocoder. is there any other method other than MKReverseGeocoder.
Thank You

Comment: @user133611 Why would you want something else? MKReverseGeocoder is the way to do it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: My problem is in my application i have to display different colored pins based on the condition. In this method "- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation"  I am using different conditions based on  [newAnnotation.annotation subtitle], But i am getting exception [Placemart subtitle] unrecognized. Actually only One pin I have to get Location Value and display it as title but for remaining Pins I am using custom Title and subtitles to display. By using the subtitles i have to categorized the pin colors

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to take a look at [Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org) for placenames lookup. It provides acess to a database with more than 8 million geolocations through a [JSON or XML api](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html). 
An objective-c wrapper of the web services can be found at ILGeoNames[3](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/developer/ilgeonames/).

Comment: +1! What a great resource--way better than Google's throttled geocoding service.